# Which solver is throwing this warning?

Tags: scikit-learn, scipy, logistic-regression

This warning pops up 10 times. The line number varies between 456 and 305:

```
C:\Users\foo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_linesearch.py:456: LineSearchWarning: The line search algorithm did not converge
  warn('The line search algorithm did not converge', LineSearchWarning)
```

I'm running a grid search with these parameters:

```
logistic_regression_grid = {
    "class_weight": ["balanced"], 
    "max_iter":     [100000],
    "solver":       ["lbfgs", "liblinear", "newton-cg", "newton-cholesky", "sag", "saga"],
    "random_state": [0]
}
```

So, the question is which solver is throwing the warning? Is it possible to determine that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the iris set and I set `max_iter=10` to purposefully induce a convergence warning. Since you are interested only in the solvers I looped over the solvers without using grid search and I was able to print which solver does not converge using the `warnings` library and the `sklearn.exceptions` package. Here is my code:

```
import warnings
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.exceptions import ConvergenceWarning
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Your logistic regression grid

logistic_regression_grid = {
    "class_weight": ["balanced"], 
    "max_iter":     [100000],
    "solver":       ["lbfgs", "liblinear", "newton-cg", "sag", "saga"],
    "random_state": [0]
}

# Load the Iris dataset

iris = load_iris()
X, y = iris.data, iris.target

# Split the data into training and testing sets

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

# Loop over the solvers and capture warnings

for solver in logistic_regression_grid["solver"]:
    with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as w:
        warnings.simplefilter("always")

        # Fit logistic regression model with the current solver

        model = LogisticRegression(class_weight="balanced", max_iter=10, solver=solver, random_state=0)
        model.fit(X_train, y_train)

        # Check if any warning was generated

        if any(issubclass(warning.category, ConvergenceWarning) for warning in w):
            print(f"Solver '{solver}' did not converge.")
```

Here is the output I get:

```
Solver 'lbfgs' did not converge.
Solver 'newton-cg' did not converge.
Solver 'sag' did not converge.
Solver 'saga' did not converge.
```